# Can't transfer the arraylist value to an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I cant get the `cardNum` value. its always come up with this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0, Size: 0

This is my code. thanks in advance for helping

```
    int playerDivide = 52 / player;
    ArrayList<String> playerCard[]= new ArrayList[player];
    for(int i = 0;i < player;i++){
        playerCard[i]=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j = 0;j < player; j++){
            for(int k = 0;k < playerDivide; k++){
                playerCard[i].add(cardNum.get(0));
                cardNum.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(playerCard[0]);
    System.out.println(playerCard[1]);
```

Comment: Which line throws the Exception?

Comment: playerCard[i].add(cardNum.get(0)); this line sir. but if i input a fix string like "x" it will popup

Comment: whats the value of player

Comment: value of the player is base on the user input, for example 3

Comment: your code above is not clear enough for us to help. Please add full of your class

Comment: **Why** are you creating an array of `ArrayList`? That seems fundamentally like a bad idea to me. What are you trying to achieve here? Why not shuffle the cards and deal them with a deck of cards (again, why an array of `ArrayList<String>` specifically)?

Comment: the value of cardNum is [D-A,D-K,D-Q,D-J,D-10,D-9,D-8,D-7,D-6,D-5,D-4,D-3,D-2,H-A,H-K,H-Q,H-J,H-10,H-9,H-8,H-7,H-6,H-5,H-4,H-3,H-2,S-A,S-K,S-Q,S-J,S-10,S-9,S-8,S-7,S-6,S-5,S-4,S-3,S-2,C-A,C-K,C-Q,C-J,C-10,C-9,C-8,C-7,C-6,C-5,C-4,C-3,C-2] if you want to ask too.

Comment: Your loop removes a value from `cardNum` on every iteration. You probably intended for it to "reset" at some point. It doesn't. Once you remove the value, it's gone. It isn't clear what this code should do, but my advice is this: check that `!cardNum.isEmpty()` ***before*** you try to take a value from it.

Comment: i wanna distribute the cardNum array between the player that the user inputs. im sorry im newbie here

Comment: the error is in ` System.out.println(playerCard[0]);
    System.out.println(playerCard[1]);`

Comment: how can i remove one part of an array that is given to another without been deleted by loop sir.

Comment: can you paste exact value of `cardNum` (initilization)

Comment: [D-A,D-K,D-Q,D-J,D-10,D-9,D-8,D-7,D-6,D-5,D-4,D-3,D-2,H-A,H-K,H-Q,H-J,H-10,H-9,H-8,H-7,H-6,H-5,H-4,H-3,H-2,S-A,S-K,S-Q,S-J,S-10,S-9,S-8,S-7,S-6,S-5,S-4,S-3,S-2,C-A,C-K,C-Q,C-J,C-10,C-9,C-8,C-7,C-6,C-5,C-4,C-3,C-2] here sir

Comment: I am trying to compile your code, and all these looks like string vlaue which are like **{"D-A","D-K", ...}**, can you add them?

Comment: i already do that on shuffling like, cut in half the altenate adding. same syntax and its working but right now in distributing its not. i dont know why its not adding in the arrays

Comment: what is the inner loop with `j` for? it is already looping up to `player` in outer loop (`i`), why again loop over all players (`j`)? sure `cardNum` is getting empty (at least when *giving* cards for second player) - (Hint: also better use `cardNum.size()` instead of `52` in calculation of `playerDivide`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code snippet, I cannot see where you are instantiationing `cardNum` variable, I believe it should be a list which is going to content the cards number you want to distribute among of the players.

something like:

```
List cardNum= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=1; i<=52; i++) {
   cardNum.add(i);
}
```

Comment: yes sir, but the cardNum has already have a value "[D-A,D-K,D-Q,D-J,D-10,D-9,D-8,D-7,D-6,D-5,D-4,D-3,D-2,H-A,H-K,H-Q,H-J,H-10,H-9,H-8,H-7,H-6,H-5,H-4,H-3,H-2,S-A,S-K,S-Q,S-J,S-10,S-9,S-8,S-7,S-6,S-5,S-4,S-3,S-2,C-A,C-K,C-Q,C-J,C-10,C-9,C-8,C-7,C-6,C-5,C-4,C-3,C-2]" and i want to distribute it base on how many players the user inputs.

Comment: if this is the initilizition, then its a single string, not array

Comment: the main reason for your problem

Comment: its an array sir, i just add "" in the comment so that you know whats the value of cardNum

Comment: You do something like that :  String cardNumberArray[] = {"D-A","D-K"};  List<String> cardNum = Arrays.asList(cardNumberArray);